# Flash BIOS on multiple computers over the network?

Tags: bios, updates, multicast

This might be a ridiculous question but is there a way to Upgrade the bios of multiple machines via the network?

We have multiple Lenovo machines that require BIOS updates that we are doing manually, and use GhostCast to cast Windows images on our computers.

I've searched around and found people asking similar questions but no response.

Any possibilities or is this just not possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are [instructions](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-70350#update) on the Lenovo site for an unattended update for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit), Vista (32-bit, 64-bit), XP. Since you did not state what system, you will need to get the files for the model(s) you are working on.

By following the instructions, you will;

> execute WINUPTP.EXE with the -s option
>
> Example: [Path where the files were extracted]\WINUPTP -s

Sounds like this could work with a script over a network or to copy the files local then execute. You obviously should test it before rolling it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to investigate [this topic](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=543911).

I have no experience with this and I basically just searched google for you, but... It talks about the PXE protocol which seems pretty interesting. It can make a computer boot from the network. They use Puppy Server to do it.

You will have to adapt the instructions to your specific needs, and you will still need to "visit" each client computer, but I don't think it's possible to do it fully automatically since BIOS flashing is not such a straightforward thing.

Perhaps you can find a quiet/force mode when using these commands that brings you even closer to your goal.